# How to properly use and define attributes within a class. tkinter sticky grid of buttons that reacts to a function individually

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a stretchy grid of buttons that change color when pressed. Using tkinter to create the grid, I think I am having issues with calling the correct root or formatting. Creating the resizing grid is not an issue, however getting the code to react to the function is providing me with problems.

Any push in the right direction will greatly be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *   
gx = 4
gy = 4
class trisector:
    def __init__(self, master):   #starts the index and root of function
        Grid.rowconfigure(master, 0, weight=1) #
        Grid.columnconfigure(master, 0, weight=1)
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)

        for x in range(gx):
            Grid.rowconfigure(frame, x , weight=1)
            for y in range(gy):

                Grid.columnconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
                self.btn = Button(frame, command=lambda widget=self.btn: 
   self.color_change(widget))
                self.btn.grid(row=x, column=y, sticky=N+E+W+S)
                self.btn.position=(x,y)

    def color_change(self,widget):
        x,y = widget.position
        print("Changing", (x,y))
        swidget.configure(bg="red")
root = Tk()
bob = trisector(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to split out the assignment of `command` to `self.btn`, since you're trying to pass the instance of the button itself:

```
self.btn = Button(frame)
self.btn['command'] = lambda widget=self.btn: self.color_change(widget)
```

And then fix the typo in `color_change()`:

```
def color_change(self,widget):
        x,y = widget.position
        print("Changing", (x,y))
        widget.configure(bg="red")   # <-- change swidget to widget
```

Comment: PRAISE IT. Thank you. "since you're trying to pass the instance of the button itself" Python cannot create the button and be set to a command?

Comment: @Ragnar Correct, `Button()` can't simultaneously create itself and assign itself to another function.  You have to allow the `Button()` to instantiate and be assigned to `self.btn` then pass `self.btn` to its own `command`.